# Why for statement doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
function main (str, d){

  var myStr = str.split(d);

  for(var x=0; x<myStr.lenght; x++){
    console.log(myStr[x]);
  }
} 

console.log(main('one-two-three-four-five','-'));
```

It should print : one two three four five on different lines but it doesn`t.Can u guys help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo in `myStr.lenght`. It should be `myStr.length`

Comment: Besides the typo, you are trying to `console.log` the return value of `main` but `main` doesn't return anything.

Comment: Man i`m so blind... Thank you, mate!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) for the length of an array.

```js
function main (str, d){
    var myStr = str.split(d);
    for (var x = 0; x < myStr.length; x++) {
    //                        ^^^^^^
        console.log(myStr[x]);
    }
} 
console.log(main('one-two-three-four-five', '-')); // this returns undefined at the end of the console
```